# gmock multiple in-out parameters SetArgReferee

Tags: reference, googlemock

I have an interface Itest:

```
class Itest {
    bool testfunction(vector<int>& v, int& id);
}
```

I can mock it with:

```
MOCK_METHOD2(testfunction, bool(vector<int>&, int&))
```

but how can I set the return values?

I tried:

```
vector<int> v;
int i;
EXPECT_CALL(testobject, testfunction(_,_, _))
            .WillOnce(testing::SetArgReferee<0>(v))
            .WillOnce(testing::SetArgReferee<1>(i))
            .WillOnce(Return(true));
```

but then it is called three times..

How do I set these `argReferees` and the return value one time?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You combine several actions together using the `DoAll` action:

```
EXPECT_CALL(testobject, testfunction(_, _, _))
    .WillOnce(DoAll(SetArgReferee<0>(v), SetArgReferee<1>(i), Return(true)));
```

See Google Mock [wiki CheatSheet](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/gmock_cheat_sheet.md#composite-actions) for more info.